# Switching between while loops with socket.io and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, while-loop, socket.io

I have an express app running socket.io on my raspberry pi which is controlling an LED panel. To drive the panel I have a while loop that is constantly updating the pixels in the panel. I want to be able to change the parameters of that loop or switch to a different loop altogether to control what animation the panel is displaying.

What is the best way to do this? When I have tried just passing a new socket.io message to the server the message isn't received because it is blocked by the loop. I can start the first animation this way but any subsequent messages are blocked.

I can provide code snippets if needed.

Comment: Code would be great!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.  Questions about code here on stackoverflow SHOULD include the relevant code.  That enables people to give faster, more accurate and complete answers without asking a lot of questions or proposing inappropriate solutions.  You can use the "edit" link below your question to add additional things to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop, use a function that calls itself asynchronously at the end. This allows events like socket.io messages to be handled before the next function execution.

The HTML page below illustrates the idea. The loop increments a counter every second and by pressing the button, you can increase the increment.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 0, increment = 1;
function loop() {
  counter += increment;
  document.querySelector("span").textContent = counter;
  setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loop()">
  <span></span>
  <button onclick="increment++">Count faster</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, `setTimeout(loop)` is "sufficiently asynchronous" to allow click events, whereas `Promise.resolve().then(loop)` would not be. As the comment below says, your code is needed for a judgment how it works for your events.

Comment: It's unclear if this is relevant to the OP's issue or not.  We need to see their code to know.